# Regex for letters, numbers, dashes only?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, regex, validation

I am trying to validate a second level domain (everything before the .com and after the https://) in Ruby so that I can pass it into my namecheap api requests. Here is what I have so far, but I am not familiar with regex

```
validates_format_of :sld, with: [a-zA-Z0-9-]
```

- no spaces allowed
- no special characters allowed
- however, dashes are allowed
- cannot start with a dash
- cannot end with a dash

I know that uppercase characters do not work in domain names, but I don't want to make users enter their text again. I will downcase the user input and show a flash message on the next page.

Comment: How many characters minimum?

Comment: 1 character minimum and 63 character maximum `presence: true, maximum: 63,`

Comment: *I know that uppercase characters do not work in domain names*. You're wrong, domain names are case insensitive.

Comment: @Barmar If you look at the actually IDN tables that registries provide to ICANN, it would appear that only lower case letters are allowed 
https://www.iana.org/domains/idn-tables/tables/actor_de_1.0.txt

Comment: @HashRocketSyntax I don't know much about IDN, but normal domain names can be any case. But domain matching is case-insensitive.

Comment: So you can write `stackoverflow.com`, `STACKOVERFLOW.COM`, or `StackOverflow.coM` and they're all equivalent.

Answer (score 4):

How about

```
validates_format_of :sld, with: /\A[a-z\d][a-z\d-]*[a-z\d]\z/i
```

Explanation:

- `\A` - match beginning of string
- `[a-z\d]` - match any letter from a-z or number from 0-9 *once*
- `[a-z\d-]` - match any letter from a-z, number from 0-9, or dash *zero or more times*
- `[a-z\d]` - match any letter from a-z or number from 0-9 *once*
- `\z` - match end of string
- `i` flag - make matches case-insensitive

Note: this will only work for strings of *length 2 or more*.  If you need to support single-character inputs,
  I would just write a method that checks the string length and if it's a single character, ensure it's not a dash.  If it's more than 2 characters, validate it with this regex.

Comment: I also added `validates :sld, presence: true, length: { minimum: 2, maximum: 30 }`

Answer (score 2):

This will probably work:

```
^[0-9A-Za-z](|[-0-9A-Za-z]{0,61}[0-9A-Za-z])$
```

- Your string needs to start with a alphanumeric (`[0-9A-Za-z]`)
- Then, there are two choices (`(|[-0-9A-Za-z]{0,61}[0-9A-Za-z])`):

  - End of string
  - Between 0 and 61 alphanumeric or dash chars followed by an alphanumeric char. (For a maximum of 63 characters)
- `^` and `$` are anchors

Comment: Thank you! I am going to give this a shot once I fix my other errors.

Answer (score 0):

```
validates :sld, format: { with: /^(?!-)[-\w\d]{,63}(?<!-)$/i }
```

You can try out your regex at http://rubular.com/

- `^(?!-)` - negative lookahead: cannot start with dash
- `[-\w\d]` - match words `\w`, digits `\d`, or dash `-`
- `{,63}` - match must be between 1 and 63 characters
- `(?<!-)$` - negative lookbehind: cannot end with dash
- `/i` - case insensitive

Comment: this allows underscores.

Comment: I liked the negative lookahead and lookbehind. But regarding the question the use of \w is problematic as @victorhazbun noted.