# Regular expression for letters, spaces and hyphens

Tags: ruby, regex

Looking for the regex to allow letters (either case), spaces and dashes for validation in ruby. Can't quite crack it.

As a starting point I'm using:

```
validates :name, format: { with: /\A[a-zA-Z]+(?: [a-zA-Z]+)?\z/, allow_blank: true}
```

Many thanks!

Comment: Welcome to SO. I suspect this question has been downvoted because it is unclear what you're asking for. I can recommend https://rubular.com/ as a resource, tho. You can use the key for parts of regexes in ruby (there are different flavours of regex in different language), and try it out for yourself.

Comment: `/\A[-A-Z\s]+\z/i` would be enough.

Comment: Also, is “λ” a letter? Is “я” a letter? Is “ä” a letter?

Comment: And what kind of [spaces](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Whitespace_character) to you want to match? Maybe provide some examples.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Regex for letters, numbers, dashes only?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41154571/regex-for-letters-numbers-dashes-only)

Comment: If you need to support all Unicode letters, make sure `-` and spaces only appear between letters and no consecutive spaces/hyphens may occur (and there may be any amount of spaces/hyphens), use `/\A\p{L}+(?:[- ]\p{L}+)*\z/`

Comment: Thanks for replies. /\A[-A-Z\s]+\z/i works perfectly. I wasn't aware there were different kinds of spaces nor there was a term for western letters. (I'd looked through a lot of other similar questions where these terms were used without being questioned and have used the same terms. Will read up on which terms to use in the future). Many thanks

Comment: Of the answers and comments so far, only @Wiktor gets it right, because there is no requirement that whitespace be permitted, only spaces. Suppose `str = "a\nb"`. Then `str.match? /\A[-A-Z\s]+\z/i #=> true`, which is incorrect, whereas `str.match? /\A\p{L}+(?:[- ]\p{L}+)*\z/ #=> false`. The former can be limited to spaces by simply changing `\s` to a space. I see this mistake time and again.

Comment: @CarySwoveland - Of all the answers, `only @Wiktor gets it right, because there is no requirement that whitespace be permitted`. Really ?  Truth is, the OP says he needs letters spaces an hyphens, not very firm requirements. Not that it begins with a letter and ends with a letter if more than 1, Not that it can't have consecutive spaces or hyphens. Not that it be letter properties. `/\A[-A-Z\s]+\z/i` works perfectly.

Comment: @sin, The question excludes newlines, tabs, form feeds and line-feeds, but your regex accepts them, because you used `\s` rather than a space. That's my only point.

Comment: @sin, "...the OP says he needs letters, spaces an hyphens" is unambiguous, but Wiktor went the extra mile to show how unreasonable combinations can be excluded, which I think is helpful, considering that it's obvious how his regex could be altered to eliminate those additional practical requirements. Moreover, I don't know why regexes continue to be so English-centric now that we can deal with Unicode so easily. Even if the context is English, the language contains many words borrowed from other languages that have diacritical marks: pass the rosé!

Answer (score 1):

If you need to support all Unicode letters and to make sure `-` and spaces only appear between letters and no consecutive spaces/hyphens may occur (and there may be any amount of spaces/hyphens), use

```rb
/\A\p{L}+(?:[- ]\p{L}+)*\z/
/\A\p{L}+(?:[-\s]\p{L}+)*\z/
/\A\p{L}+(?:[-\p{Zs}\t]\p{L}+)*\z/
```

In short,

- `\A` - matches start of string
- `\p{L}+` - one or more letters
- `(?:[-\s]\p{L}+)*` - a non-capturing group that matches zero or more occurrences of

  - `[-\s]` - a `-` or whitespace
  - `\p{L}+` - one or more Unicode letters
- `\z` - the end of string.

See the [**regex demo**](https://rubular.com/r/10Ss8lOkS4sNMN).

In the comments, you mention that `/\A[-A-Z\s]+\z/i` works for you, but it also matches blank strings, or strings that are a mix of hyphens and whitespace because it means "start of string, one or more ASCII letters, whitespace or hyphens and then the end of string". This can be used to allow only specific chars to be input, but this does not validate much.

Answer (score -1):

This regex will allow letters, spaces and hyphens: `/\A[A-Za-z\s\-]+\z/`

Comment: Careful, `^` and `$` are beginning/ending of *line* in Ruby, not *string*. You almost always want `\A` and `\z` instead.